# How to list Internal/External storage files absolute path in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, filesystems

I have searched and tried so many tutorials but i haven't got any working code for listing internal/external storage files absolute path.

I do have code for access only one file from internal storage -

```
 var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var filename = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "test.mp3");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files/

Answer (score 0):

This code gets the external storage path. It return the emulated copy if there is no actual removable device.

```
var _path = GetExternalFilesDirs(null);
string Datapath;
foreach (var spath in _path)
{
    if (spath == null) //just loop on if there is no card inserted
        continue;
    if (Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageEmulated(spath))
    {   //Emulated
        Datapath = spath.AbsolutePath.ToString();                
    }
    else if (Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageRemovable(spath))
    {   //removable
        Datapath = spath.AbsolutePath.ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```